# Making md-fab bigger in Angular Material design

Tags: material-design, angular-material

Was playing around with md-fab, but wanted a REALLy big md-fab button (100px) rather than the 48 and 64 px size, but seems quite problematic to achieve that, thought maybe I could be smart and just create a class as follows

```
.bigfab {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Then a button as

```
<button class="md-fab bigfab" >Click<br>me!</button>
```

While it does work, it goes quite ugly, and the highlight dies. So any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found a (possible) solution

Skip md-fab, use md-raised, you get a square shadow, but such is life :)

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-warn bigfab" >Makes clothes!</md-button>
```